# Haskell: TVar: orElse

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc, stm, tvar

Is the "else" part of [`orElse`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/GHC-Conc.html#v%3aorElse) called when a transaction is retried due to another transaction writing to a `TVar` it had read, or only when [`retry`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/GHC-Conc.html#v%3aretry) is explicitly called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have

> orElse a b

then `b` is only run if `retry` is called explicitly in `a`. Otherwise `orElse` would essentially become nondeterministic. (The rerunning of transactions that is done by the STM runtime is transparent and should not effect the outcome of any computation.)